# Regex causing Pattern Syntax Exception

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a #replaceAll regex to file out certain characters.

I tried the following

```
msg.replaceAll("[^\\w~!@#$%^&*()-=_+`[]{}\\|:;'\"<>,./\\]", "");
```

but it gave me this error

```
INFO Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 36
07.09 00:07:24 [Server] INFO [^\w~!@#$%^&*()-=_+`[]{}\|:;'"<>,./\]
07.09 00:07:24 [Server] INFO ^
```

I've tried searching online but don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to escape `-`, `[` and `]` inside your character class

Comment: @Nick Do I escape with one \ or two \\

Comment: Just single \ should be enough.

Comment: Not 100% certain for java but I think it's two.

Comment: @Nick It's telling me 'Invalid escape sequence'

Comment: you sure need two for java , otherwise is is *just* escaping for java String (that also uses backslash for escaping)

Answer (score 1):

For your regex expression,you have add `\\` before the last `]` and do not escape for the first `[`,and also you need to escape `-`,after changing it to

```
[^\w~!@#$%^&*()\-=_+`\[\]{}\|:;'\"<>,./]
```

it works fine in my side

```
msg = msg.replaceAll("[^\\w~!@#$%^&*()\\-=_+`\\[\\]{}\\|:;'\\\"<>,./]", "");
```

Comment: This worked but for some reason it's not replacing '\'

Comment: @Dan for '\' you need to escape itself

Comment: Isn't that way '\\\' does?

Comment: @Dan you need to use '\\\\' four backslash instead

Comment: BTW it is not the "before the last `]`" - the last one should not be escaped since closing the `[]` pattern (example/code is correct (in that regard))

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that maybe this expression might be desired or close to one:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){


        final String regex = "[^\\w~!@#$%^&*()=_+`\\[\\]{}|:;'\"<>,.\\\/-]";
        final String string = "ábécédééefg";
        final String subst = "";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
bcdefg
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HUkIDc/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/HUkIDc/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: just a little note: `regex101` does not have the Java flavor, there might be some minor differences